# Getting Index Highest Lower values in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

`Textbox1.Lines:` I want to display in a textbox descending values but not the value and the line where that value is. I don't really know how to use what I have below to achieve this.

```
 
44
77
101
101
67
```

> Expected Output: By Index Descending Values. (index 0)

```
2 
3
1
4
0
```

Code one:

```
Dim lines() As String = TextBox1.Lines
Dim value As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)
For Each line As String In lines
    value.Add(Convert.ToInt32(line))
Next
value.Sort()
value.Reverse()
TextBox2.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, value)
```

Code two:

```
Dim lines() As String = TextBox1.Lines
Dim value = lines.Select(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x)).OrderByDescending(Function(x) x)
TextBox2.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit messy, but you could use a `Tuple` to achieve this by storing the numeric value of the line in `Item1` and the index in `Item2`:

```
Dim lines() As String = TextBox1.Lines
Dim value As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer))

' Build list of each line value and it's index
For i = 0 To lines.Length - 1 Step 1
    value.Add(New Tuple(Of Integer, Integer)(Convert.ToInt32(lines(i)), i))
Next
value.Sort()
value.Reverse()

' Output results
TextBox2.Text = String.Empty
For Each Item As Tuple(Of Integer, Integer) In value
    TextBox2.Text += Item.Item2.ToString() + vbNewLine
Next
```

This way your list is sorted in descending order like you require, but when you output the results you use the index (stored in `Item2`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ, you can access the index used in iterating over the items by declaring it as the second parameter like `.Select(Function(b, i) ...)`. You can incorporate it into the data by making a new anonymous type like `.Select(Function(b, i) New With {.n = CInt(b), .idx = i})`.

From there, you just need to order it by the number and select the index, a quick conversion to a string for the numbers and get it as an array and you have:

```
TextBox2.Lines = TextBox1.Lines.
    Where(Function(a) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a)).
    Select(Function(b, i) New With {.n = CInt(b), .idx = i}).
    OrderByDescending(Function(c) c.n).
    Select(Function(d) CStr(d.idx)).
    ToArray()
```

Comment: Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid. maybe it is because there is no value on the first line (index 0)?

Comment: @CristianCristian Oh, I didn't see that empty line... I've added a filter to exclude those. (And I edited the question to add an `&thinsp;` so a line of whitespace shows.)